# Assign latest date (from API) to identifier (in spreadsheet) using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with a list of identifiers in the first column (e.g. COLTS or RAMS). Using Google Apps Script I then fetch transaction data for these identifiers from an API (multiple transactions per identifier). That data looks like this:

```
{
"sportsfolio_transactions":[
    {
"trans_date":"06/26/2017 9:58:00 AM",
"amount":-10.30,
"trans_type_id":1,
"trans_type_name":"Buy",
"stock_id":"COLTS",
"shares":3
    },
{
"trans_date":"04/25/2017 2:58:00 AM",
"amount":-3.22,
"trans_type_id":1,
"trans_type_name":"Buy",
"stock_id":"COLTS",
"shares":1
}

{
"trans_date":"05/20/2017 2:58:00 AM",
"amount":-30.22,
"trans_type_id":1,
"trans_type_name":"Buy",
"stock_id":"RAMS",
"shares":9
}]}
```

The code I have so far filters for buy transactions and looks like this:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('apidata'); active spreadsheet
var output = [];

  data["sportsfolio_transactions"].forEach(function(elem,i) {

  output.push([elem["stock_id"],elem["shares"],elem["trans_type_name"],elem["trans_date"],elem["amount"]]);

});

var outputbuy = [];

data["sportsfolio_transactions"].forEach(function(element,i) {
if(element["trans_type_name"] == "Buy") {

 outputbuy.push([element["stock_id"],element["shares"],element["trans_type_name"],element["trans_date"],element["amount"]]);

}
});
```

Now I would like to put the date of the latest transaction next to each identifier.
E.g. according to the above data, next to COLTS should be the date 06/26/2017

After hours of trying (math.max, sorting, etc.) I'm out of ideas and hope that you can help me out here. Oh, and if you see any possible improvements for the posted code, of course that is also much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the problem solved, sort of. Can only look into "Buy" transactions, was not able to get "Buy" || "Sell" to work properly.

Also, this code seems awefully inefficient, but it's the best I was able to produce. Any ideas on how to make it more efficient?

Here's the code:

```
function getLastTrade() {

var url= 'https://asmwebdev1.azurewebsites.net/api/get_sportsfolio_transactions/'

var today = new Date()
var enddate = Utilities.formatDate(today,"GMT", "MM/dd/YYYY");

var formData = {
  'email': 'xxxxx',
  'password': 'x',
  'sportsfolio_key': '9657',
  'start_date': '01/01/2017',
  'end_date': enddate,
};

var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : formData
 };

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

var json = response.getContentText();

var data = JSON.parse(json);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('apidata');

var Avals = ss.getRange("A2:A50").getValues();
var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

for(var row=2;row<Alast+2;row++){  

  var oldestdate = new Date(0)

  data["sportsfolio_transactions"].forEach(function(element,i) {

    var lastid = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValues();  

    if(element["stock_id"] == lastid && element["trans_type_name"] == "Buy"){

      var newestdate = new Date(element["trans_date"])

    if(newestdate>oldestdate) {

   oldestdate = newestdate

   }

   sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue(oldestdate) 

  }

});

}  

}
```

The data that the API returns contains hundreds of transactions, a small sample can be seen in the post above.